# Missing "missing sentinel" warning for exec in C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, compiler-warnings

GCC will helpfully warn you if you forget to include the NULL sentinel at the end of a call to one of the [exec(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) functions:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  execlp("test", "test", "arg1");
}
```

Sample compiler output for GCC 4.8:

```
$ g++ test.cc -Wformat
test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cc:4:32: warning: missing sentinel in function call [-Wformat=]
   execlp("test", "test", "arg1");
                            ^
$
```

However, if you compile in C++11 mode, no diagnostic is printed:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11 -Wformat
$
```

Why is this warning not available in C++11? Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: The same appears to happen with `-std=c++98`.

Comment: You need something like `-std=gnuXX` (default is 98), apparently.

Comment: Indeed `-std=gnu11` brings the warnings back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`execlp` is not a standard C function. For the compiler to recognize it as a "standard" function, for which it knows what the arguments should look like, you need `-std=gnu++11` instead of `-std=c++11`. Note that the default is `-std=gnu++98`. Glibc could improve the situation by specifying the `sentinel` attribute on the declaration of `execlp`.